# GDI+ leaks memory when deleting pointers as GdiplusBase*?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, gdi+

I'm trying to work with GDI+ and I'm running into a weird memory leak. I have a `vector` of `GdiplusBase` pointers, all of them dynamically created. The odd thing is, though, is that if I try to delete the objects as `GdiplusBase` pointers, e.g.,

```
vector<GdiplusBase*> gdiplus;
gdiplus.push_back(new Image(L"filename.jpg"));
delete gdiplus[0];
```

The object is not deleted and memory leaks (according to Task Manager). However, if I cast back to the original pointer and then delete,

```
delete (Image*)gdiplus[0];
```

The object is correctly deleted. The strange this about this, as far as I can tell, is that (according to MSDN) [`GdiplusBase` is the base class of all GDI+ objects and owns the delete operators for all of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534451(VS.85).aspx). In that case, shouldn't `delete gdiplus[0];` work correctly and free the memory? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine the problem is that `GdiplusBase` does not have a virtual destructor, and thus when you call `delete` like that, no destructor is called. And the destructor of `Image` is likely releasing some other resources (such as bitmap handles etc). So the memory for the `Image` *object* itself is freed correctly, but other resources it is using (which may also use up memory) aren't freed.